# readTextAsync in winjs does not always read my file

Tags: javascript, winjs, promise

My question is about `readTextAsync` and `writeTextAsync` in the context of windows store applications. I have searched StackOverflow and MSDN and also otherwise Googled extensively.

My code is given below:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingFolder.getFileAsync("sample.txt")
    .then(
        function(samplefile){
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(samplefile)
        },
        function(e){},
        function(samplefile){
            Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(samplefile)
        }
    )
    .done(
        function(something){ data = something; },
        function(){},
        function(something){ data = something; }
    );
```

My problem is that most of the time the file does not get read.  When I debug, it gets read intermittently.

It appears to be an issue of not allowing enough time for the async call to complete.
I am totally new to Windows app programming and javascript.

I would appreciate any help.  Thanks.  ravi

Comment: Why are your error handlers empty? What do you intend the progress handlers to do, especially the one in the `then`? And what is that assignment to `data`???

Comment: Bergi - thanks for the comments.  Haven't decided what to do in case of an error.  That is the reason for the emptry error handler.  In the progress handler for then, I am just trying to repeat the call, to ensure completion.  I want the text that is read to be stored in data for processing later.

Comment: How does the issue show up? Are there any errors, is the data fragmentary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whan you chain many promises you should have one error function at the end where you put your "done".

In this way you will be able to see if there is an error while it is reading.

The way you should write it is:

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.roamingFolder.getFileAsync("sample.txt")
.then(
    function(samplefile){
        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(samplefile)
    }
)
.done(
    function(data){ //do something with your data, like assign to a list  },
    function(error){ //do something with error },
    function(data){ //do something with your data } //progress function,not sure what you want to do with this
);
```

But this call may not be your problem, if you put this code in a normal function and then call it, you will not be able to see the `data` object because it will be loaded in an asynchronous way.

**You have to process your data inside the done function** because if you assing it to an external variable (your `data` object) like you did, that variable will be empty when you try to use because most likely the done method hasn't occured yet.

Comment: Maurizio - thanks for your corrected code, and the explanation.  I believe I am beginning to understand my problem.  Basically, what I am trying to do is to store a list of names in a file - one name in a record, and then retrieve the names from the file and populate a listview or dropdown list control.  How do I ensure that the async call is complete, and there are no errors?  i.e. all the names in the file have been read and loaded into the list?  would appreciate any help you can offer.  thanks.

Comment: if the code step into the first function of the .done method, that means the file was read and there is not error. you can assign the result to a list in there.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Essentially I was missing the point that the required processing must be happen in the .done method.  I got it now.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> In the progress handler for then, I am just trying to repeat the call, to ensure completion.

That makes no sense. It might even lead to race conditions, since you try to read the file *while* getting it is still *in progress*. Also, the repeated call does not return anything, and the task will not be chained into / synchronized with the flow of the rest. Remove that handler.

> The reason for the emptry error handler is I haven't decided what to do in case of an error.

You can just omit it then. Errors would then just "bubble" up, and can be caught in other promises that depend on the failed one.

> I want the text that is read to be stored in `data` for processing later.

But *when* is "later"? You would need to ensure that the processing does not start before the file is completely read - for which you will need to hook a `done` handler on your promise. Do the processing in the promise chain as well, never use global/higher-scoped variables with promises. If you need `data` multiple times, you can simple store the promise in a variable, and attach multiple `done` handlers (which will work even when the promise is already resolved).

Comment: Bergi - thanks for the explanations.  You have helped me get my thinking right in many ways.